# Using Vaadin in Netbeans 8.1

Tags: maven, netbeans, vaadin

I've just installed the Vaadin plugin (version 1.2.1) in NetBeans 8.1 (on Windows 10) and it appears to be working correctly until I create a new project. I can select a Vaadin template from a list of choices but when I click for a new Vaadin Web application I get a build failure with the following output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------  Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>

<<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<

--- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom --- Generating project in Batch mode Archetype repository not defined. Using the one from [com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:7.7.7] found in catalog remote
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
BUILD FAILURE
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 5.096s Finished at: Wed Feb 15 20:31:32 GMT 2017 Final Memory: 14M/155M
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:7.7.7) -> [Help 1]

    To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I'm not an expert on Maven so I'll need some help here. The Maven plugin is up to date and Maven projects can be  created as normal so there's no problem there.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you try to create a vaadin 7.7.6 project (I think the 7.7.7 is not yet released)

Comment: I just tried a re-run with 7.7.6 as the archetypeVersion parameter with the same result.

Comment: Did you hit the ***Clean-and-Build*** button (hammer-and-broom icon)? You must do this after getting the project established, though this step is not at all obvious.

Comment: The trouble is that the project isn't actually created at all, so I can't try that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a nasty bug in our archetypes. One essential artifact was not published -> creating projects was broken. For some reason it worked for users who had created a project before with an older version.

This should be fixed now (yesterday). If you have issue, you can try to create it via command line with additional "-U" flag. If it still doesn't work, let me know and we'll investigate it more.

Answer (score 0):

I did just test it with netbeans 8.2 and it creates vaadin 7.7.7 projects correctly.

Do you also use the Vaadin type, or do you create a project from maven targets?

[image: Create new project]

Comment: I used the Vaadin type, just like your screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until all the project dependencies are downloaded.(Hit the build button and wait for few minutes, depending on your Internet connection speed)

Comment: Unfortunately that option isn't available as there is no project to build. The build failure means that no project is actually created.

Comment: Instead of creating a new project using Vaadin plugin, try creating a new project using Maven only, plus use the archetype sub-option. Then, in the archetype search, type Vaadin, and then select vaadin-web-application from the listed archetypes. I hope it works for you this way.

Comment: I just tried that and it worked. There was no vaadin-web-application Artifact-ID, so I used vaadin-jee7-webapp-archetype instead, but the project runs as per your suggestion.

Comment: Good. :-). Now you can create a new project using Vaadin Plugin for NetBeans. It should work now as expected.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I still get a build failure for a new Vaadin project as mentioned above.

Comment: Probably you need to switch to NetBeans 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the Build Failure - use the 'rerun with different parameters' option in the Output window, replacing 7.7.7 with 7.7.6 (see image) and it creates a new Maven web project as desired.

[image]

I guess I'll just have to wait until it works for a 7.7.7 project.